# Difference in displaying cv2 Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

Why is there a difference when displaying the entire matrix Mat and the matrix as individual elements?

```
cv::Point2f sour[4] = {Point(530,430), Point(670, 320), Point(870,430), Point(980, 320)};
cv::Point2f dest[4] = {Point(450,530), Point(450,420), Point(550,530), Point(550,420)};

cv::Mat hom(3, 3, CV_32F);
hom=getPerspectiveTransform(sour,dest);

cout << "hom: " <<hom << endl;
```

prints

```
hom: [0.4489795918367541, 1.122448979591883, -33.67346938776892;
  5.034167527284694e-15, 2.040816326530671, -68.48979591837563;
  1.505685767039244e-17, 0.001224489795918431, 1]
```

while

```
for (int i1=0; i1<3; i1++){
    for (int i2=0; i2<3; i2++){
            cout << hom.at<float>(i1,i2) << " ";
        }
        cout <<endl;
    }
```

prints:

```
-1.32615e+23 1.72449 1.70011e-29 
0 0.0301113 -2.30304e-37 
0 0.0147314 -3.2706e+24
```

Comment: Did you check that ```hom.type() == cv::DataType<float>::type``` after assigning it a homography. Maybe the datatype silently changed to double?

Comment: If that is the case, then the solution would be to replace ```hom.at<float>``` by ```hom.at<double>```. If you want to be sure to have a matrix of the right type, you could replace the declaration of ```hom``` by ```cv::Matx<float, 3, 3> hom;```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possibility that I see is that the matrix type changed from `float` to `double` after assigning it (`hom=getPerspectiveTransform(sour,dest);`). If that is the case, then `CV_Assert(hom.type() == cv::DataType<float>::type);` is going to throw an exception.

To address that, you need to refer to the matrix elements by the correct type, probably `double`. So when you print the matrix, replace `hom.at<float>` by `hom.at<double>` and see if that helps.

By the way, I see no reason to first declare the matrix like `cv::Mat hom(3, 3, CV_32F);`. You can probably directly do `cv::Mat hom = getPerspectiveTransform(sour, dest);`.

Another solution to this problem is to use a statically typed matrix, that is
`cv::Matx<float, 3, 3> hom = getPerspectiveTransform(sour, dest);`. OpenCV will automatically convert the value returned by `getPerspectiveTransform` to the correct type in the assignment. Then, when you print the elements, you can replace `hom.at<float>(i1, i2)` by `hom(i1, i2)` since the element type is now statically known.

*Update:*
The fact that the `<<` operator seems to print the elements of the `hom` matrix with about 16 decimal digits suggests that the precision is `double`. For single precision (`float`) it would have been about 7 decimal digits.